# Any way to detected change made in the DOM by Angularjs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, dom, html5-history

In jQuery, I'm trying to detect change made in the DOM by AngularJS, is this possible?  I already got a AJAX and history change listener, but these doesn't seem to detect change.

Comment: worse case scenario stringify the dom on page load, and then stringify it again whenever you want to check for changes, then compare the strings.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: This question needs more context. Which problem are you trying to solve and what kind of DOM changes are you interested in? Reaching for JQuery is rarely the right solution so there's a good chance whatever usecase you have can be solved in a different way.

Comment: Maybe you should drop the idea of using jQuery with Angular and do it just the Angular way, I'm happy to help if you provide some code

Comment: I needed to detect change into the DOM tree so I could inject some code.  I switch from event bubbling to event capturing and I was able to attach event to DOM element that were later added by Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Directives are the way to handle this in most cases:

```
<input type="text" detectchange>

app.directive('detectchange',function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,element,attr) {
            element.on('change',function() {
                console.log('change made');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to detect change into the DOM tree so I could inject some code on the newly added DOM element.  I switch from event bubbling to event capturing and I was able to attach event to DOM element that were later add by Angular.